# Setup and Teardown (and self invalidating) EmberJS Views

Tags: sproutcore, ember.js

I would like to have the ability to setup and teardown functions for views inside EmberJS, for this example I will say displaying logs that are fetched via AJAX every 5 seconds, buts its a problem I encounter quite a lot

I have created a switchView method here which will handle the setup / teardown events, however right now it cant invalidate itself to show the updated information.

```
Em.Application.create({

  wrapper: $('#content'),
  currentView: null,

  ready: function() {

    this._super();

    this.self = this;

    Em.routes.add('/log/', this, 'showLogs');
    Em.routes.add('*', this, 'show404');

  },

  switchView: function(name, view) {

    if (this.currentView) {
      $(document.body).removeClass('page-' + this.currentView.name);

      if (this.currentView.view.unload) {
        this.currentView.view.unload();
      }

      this.currentView.view.remove();
    }

    if (name) {
      $(document.body).addClass('page-' + name);
    }

    if (view.load) {
      view.load();
    }
    view.appendTo(this.wrapper);
    this.currentView = {name: name, view: view};
  }

});


var LogView = Ember.View.create({

  templateName: 'logs',

  logs: [],

  load: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.interval = setInterval(function() {
      self.fetchLogs.apply(self);
    }, 5000);
    this.fetchLogs();
  },

  unload: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },

  fetchLogs: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.get('/logs', function(data) {
      self.logs = data.list;
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at Ember.State/Ember.ViewState and Ember.StateManager: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/master/packages/ember-states

I think documentation is still weak but looking at the tests may help...

Comment: It should be noted that `ember-states` is no longer part of core.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking for, but you should look into `willInsertElement`, `didInsertElement` and `willDestroyElement`. These are all called relative to the view element's insertion and removal from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at the end of the RunLoop:

```
Ember.run.schedule('timers', function () {
   //update your widget
});
```

See http://blog.sproutcore.com/the-run-loop-part-1/. The same concept is present in EmberJS